# I can't open a window to save a csv file using php

Tags: php, csv, export

I am trying to create a button to save in csv the result of a query using php. I can't get a window to save the file.
In this first page, a table is created and the user could save the result by clicking on the button that sends data to export.php :
Here's the extract:

```
echo "
        <form name='export' action='export.php' method='post' >
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-info'>Exporter le résultat en CSV</button>" ;
    $listope = pg_fetch_all($marequete) ;
    "<input type='hidden' value="; echo $listope; "name='listope'>

        </form>" ;
```

In the second part i.e. export.php, The csv should be created :

```
<?php
//prolongation session
session_start() ; 
//importation config.php
require('./require/config.php');
//Generate the CSV file header
header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=donnees.csv");

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// loop over the rows, outputting them

foreach ($_POST['listope'] as $line) {
    fputcsv($output, $line);
    } ; 
print $output ;
?>
```

For some reason, it seems that nothing is sent to export.php. None window appears.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['listope'])`, what do you see?

Comment: _“For some reason, it seems […]”_ - sounds like a fantastic debug effort on your end so far :-/ First of all, comment out the headers, so that you see the result of the script directly in the browser. Secondly, enable proper PHP error reporting, if you have not done so already. Report back with the results here. Third, remove `print $output ;`, that makes no sense whatsoever here. You can not output the content of the resource behind an opened file pointer simply using `print`; but it is not necessary here to begin with, because you are writing directly to the output stream already.

Comment: I can't get a result but if I open the export.php page, I have    `<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>C:\ms4w\Apache\site\form_php\metadonnees\export.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />
Resource id #4NULL`. Issue with $listope so...

Comment: I commented headers and write a var_dump as demanded. I get in return : Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in `C:\ms4w\Apache\site\form_php\metadonnees\export.php on line 19` and 
`NULL` for the var_dump. I hope I did what you asked for. Thx